# transfer data between one class methods in python

Tags: python, class, oop, parameter-passing

i have one class

```
class worker:   
    def __init__(self, mainProject, victims):
        self.mainProject = mainProject
        self.victims = victims
    def mainWork(self, mainProject, victims):
        ...
    def send(self):
        ...
```

in **mainWork()** i define some vars, browser object and other data, i need to transfer them to **send()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign and read whatever you want in `self`:

```
def mainWork(self, mainProject, victims):
    self.whatever = 42
def send(self):
    print self.whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:-

```
class worker:   
    def __init__(self, mainProject, victims):
        self.mainProject = mainProject
        self.victims = victims
    def send(self):
        print self.mainProject, self.victims

def main():
    w = worker('programming', 'Jess')
    w.send()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```